# How to change API level from 15 to 16 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I was using Nexus S in eclipse and now I changed it to Galaxy Nexus. Now I want to change api level from 15 to 16. I went through project->properties->android but it is showing only two option 15 and 8 for api level and it is for previous version of android that is Nexus S 4.0.3 and 2.2 respectively. How can I change api level to 16 for galaxy Nexus.

Comment: run sdk and download the desire android api version

Comment: u need to download and install then from sdk manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the sdk for api level 16 you can get it from [here](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) download the file manually and place it inside your sdk folder or you can open your sdk manager and download it from there

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the corresponding sdk (16) ?

Check this doc for details
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install the Android sdk plugin for eclipse

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

and then you will be able to download the API you need;)

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK manager ->>Go to tools -->> Go to option ->> and check if option for "Force/https:..."is checked.... And than go back you will see all the api's.Check only that Api which you want to install.